# Kafka failed to start using confluent command

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to start ZooKeeper, Kafka and schema registry via :

```
$confluent start schema-registry
```

I'm running a cluster of 3 nodes, and for some reason when I run above command, Kafka is unable to start :

```
#root: /confluent/confluent-5.0.0/bin/confluent start schema-registry
This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.h266AuQQ
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
/Kafka failed to start
kafka is [DOWN]
Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
```

zookeeper.properties :

```
root: /confluent/confluent-5.0.0# cat ./etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties 

tickTime=2000
dataDir=/infrastructure/zookeeper/data/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=Hostname.DOMAIN.com:2888:3888
server.2=Hostname.DOMAIN.com:2888:3888
server.3=Hostname.DOMAIN.com:2888:3888
```

Kafka log :

```
root: /confluent/confluent-5.0.0# ./bin/confluent log kafka

[2018-08-16 14:09:02,830] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-08-16 14:09:02,830] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-08-16 14:09:03,422] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,201] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,201] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,304] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,306] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,307] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,310] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZooKeeperClient.scala:230)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$$anonfun$kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected$1.apply(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.kafka$zookeeper$ZooKeeperClient$$waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:226)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:95)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1580)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.kafka$server$KafkaServer$$createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:348)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:372)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:202)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:117)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,312] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,313] WARN  (kafka.utils.CoreUtils$)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer$$anonfun$shutdown$5.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaServer.scala:579)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.swallow(CoreUtils.scala:86)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.shutdown(KafkaServer.scala:579)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:329)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.startup(SupportedServerStartable.java:117)
        at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:66)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,315] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-08-16 14:09:04,316] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Not sure what this line tells me:

```
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
```

Seems like there is also something wrong regarding the Zookeeper as appear in logs:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:558)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:610)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:838)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:957)
[2018-08-16 14:32:26,540] INFO Resolved hostname: HOSTNAME1.DNS.com to address: HOSTNAME1.DNS.com/10.***.***.*** (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2018-08-16 14:32:26,540] WARN Cannot open channel to 3 at election address HOSTNAME1.DNS.com/10.***.***.***:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:558)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:610)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:838)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:957)
[2018-08-16 14:32:26,541] INFO Resolved hostname: HOSTNAME2.DNS.com to address: HOSTNAME2.DNS.com/10.***.***.*** (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2018-08-16 14:32:26,541] INFO Notification time out: 60000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection)
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Schema registry cannot start because Kafka brokers are down. Therefore, you need to find out why Kafka brokers are not up and running. It would much helpful if you provide server.properties files as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying, correct me if I'm wrong but "confluent start" command should bring up all kafka brokers, this is why they are all down right now. This issue is that the command fails to bring them up, and I'm not sure why. This is why these logs were posted.

Comment: Well confluent start will bring up all kafka brokers if you provide the correct properties and configuration in server.properties file(s)

Comment: To make things more clear: Schema registry requires Kafka brokers to be up and running while kafka brokers in turn, require zookeeper instance(s) to be up and running. Start by running each service individually; for example `confluent start zookeeper` and wait for a few minutes. Read the logs and make sure that everything is OK, then do the same for each of the brokers. Did you try to run an environment with only one Kafka broker?

Comment: Last time I checked, confluent command only is able to run a single broker+Zookeeper (locally, not connect to remote servers)

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem starting zookeper.

Below lines are not required in zookeeper properties because kafka property file contain zokkeeper address which connect all nodes.

server.1 Hostname.DOMAIN.com:2888:3888

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I have a similar problem. When I started confluent  got:

```
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
Kafka failed to start
kafka is [DOWN]
Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
```

The problem was that I was running before Kafka locally, and the port 9092 was still listening a process. So first I check if the port was listening:

```
sudo lsof -i :9092
```

Out:

> COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME java
>   17150 savi01   97u  IPv6 134739      0t0  TCP *:9092 (LISTEN) java
>   17150 savi01  113u  IPv6 134741      0t0  TCP
>   localhost:42368->savi01:9092 (CLOSE_WAIT)

Then I kill the process:

```
sudo kill -9 17150
```

Now I run confluent again and everything is working. Hope that helps for future consultant